# What is the library for using google maps in Angular 4 application?

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am writing an angular 4 web application and I want to integrate the google maps in it? What is the best? Which library should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[`Angular Google Maps (AGM)`](https://angular-maps.com/)** library which is quite popular.

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
```

Comment: I am using the same library, but i wanted to make changes like custom marker, i dont know how to do it?

Comment: Hello Anil,Sajjeetharan is right, this is another question, but for custom marker simply use param iconUrl on agm-marker ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AGM](https://angular-maps.com/) and below is the code to enter:

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'
    })
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

In HTML,

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="15" [streetViewControl]="true" [styles]="styleArray">
    <agm-marker iconUrl="assets/images/map_marker.png" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Read [Docs](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/) to Get Started

Comment: @Anil you can change marker by using `agm-marker` tag. See answer above.